# Webpack production build is returning development build everytime

Tags: reactjs, webpack

On a ReactJS project, it is using **webpack** for building it. Everytime I run the script for production build, it is giving me a development build (getting *This page is using the development build of React*. from React Developer Tools). I need to get the production build.

The webpack has been configured by some other developer who's not around and I don't have any prior experience with webpack. So I am facing a really hard time to resolve the error.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "enquiry-form-rnd-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cross-env BUILD_ENV=dev  webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --progress --colors --port 3002",
    "build:stage": "BUILD_ENV=STAGE webpack  --mode production",
    "build:prod": "BUILD_ENV=prod webpack  --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-open": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-datetime": "^2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-intl": "^2.8.0",
    "react-notifications-component": "^1.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-responsive": "^6.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-icons": "^7.14.0",
    "validator": "^11.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", "css"]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    host: "172.16.228.94",
    // host: "192.168.2.108",
    port: 3002
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      "process.env.DEBUG": JSON.stringify(process.env.BUILD_ENV),
      "process.env.BUILD_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.BUILD_ENV)
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: I believe you should pass flags like this `--mode=production`, also try add `-p` option to build script `"build:prod": "BUILD_ENV=prod webpack  -p --mode=production"`

Comment: @RafaelHovsepyan That's exactly what I was looking for!